# Why are there top-level words in Akkadian dictionary, all of which are unpronounceable directly?

Tags: dictionary, akkadian

I have been digging into the [Oracc RINAP dataset](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/rinap/rinapdownloads/index.html), which includes lots of "grammatical *entries*" in a huge JSON file, an example entry which looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5f6292088acbc5d9ce3430231aa450ce):

```
{
  "headword": "abāku[lead away]V",
  "id": "x000006440",
  "icount": "14",
  "ipct": "100",
  "xis": "akk.r00009f",
  "dc_title": "rinap/akk/abāku[lead away]",
  "cf": "abāku",
  "gw": "lead away",
  "pos": "V",
  "forms": [
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.1",
      "n": "a-bu-ka",
      "c": "108",
      "icount": "4",
      "ipct": "29",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a0"
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.2",
      "n": "a-bu-uk",
      "c": "112",
      "icount": "3",
      "ipct": "21",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a1"
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.3",
      "n": "e-ba-ku-ma",
      "c": "2571",
      "icount": "1",
      "ipct": "7",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a2"
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.4",
      "n": "e-bu-ku-nim-ma",
      "c": "2581",
      "icount": "2",
      "ipct": "14",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a3"
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.5",
      "n": "e-bu-uk-ma",
      "c": "2583",
      "icount": "1",
      "ipct": "7",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a4"
    },
    {
      "type": "form",
      "id": "x00000644.6",
      "n": "i-bu-ka-ma",
      "c": "4299",
      "icount": "3",
      "ipct": "21",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a5"
    }
  ],
  "norms": [
    {
      "id": "x00000644.7",
      "icount": "3",
      "ipct": "21",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a1",
      "n": "ābuk",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.8",
          "ref": "x00000644.2",
          "icount": "3",
          "ipct": "21",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "x00000644.9",
      "icount": "4",
      "ipct": "29",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a0",
      "n": "ābuka",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.10",
          "ref": "x00000644.1",
          "icount": "4",
          "ipct": "29",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "x00000644.11",
      "icount": "1",
      "ipct": "7",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a2",
      "n": "ēbakūma",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.12",
          "ref": "x00000644.3",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "7",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "x00000644.13",
      "icount": "1",
      "ipct": "7",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a4",
      "n": "ēbukma",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.14",
          "ref": "x00000644.5",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "7",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "x00000644.15",
      "icount": "2",
      "ipct": "14",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a3",
      "n": "ēbukunimma",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.16",
          "ref": "x00000644.4",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "14",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "x00000644.17",
      "icount": "3",
      "ipct": "21",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a5",
      "n": "ībukāma",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "normform",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.18",
          "ref": "x00000644.6",
          "icount": "3",
          "ipct": "21",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "senses": [
    {
      "type": "sense",
      "id": "x00000644.19",
      "n": "abāku[lead away//deliver]V'V",
      "icount": "1",
      "ipct": "7",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a6",
      "num": "1.",
      "pos": "V",
      "mng": "deliver",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.20",
          "n": "a-bu-uk",
          "ref": "x00000644.2",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "100",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a6"
        }
      ],
      "norms": [
        {
          "id": "x00000644.21",
          "n": "ābuk",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "100",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a6"
        }
      ],
      "sigs": [
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.22",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:a-bu-uk=abāku[lead away//deliver]V'V$ābuk",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "100",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "sense",
      "id": "x00000644.23",
      "n": "abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V",
      "icount": "13",
      "ipct": "93",
      "xis": "akk.r0000a7",
      "num": "2.",
      "pos": "V",
      "mng": "lead away",
      "forms": [
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.24",
          "n": "a-bu-ka",
          "ref": "x00000644.1",
          "icount": "4",
          "ipct": "31",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a0"
        },
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.25",
          "n": "a-bu-uk",
          "ref": "x00000644.2",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a8"
        },
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.26",
          "n": "e-ba-ku-ma",
          "ref": "x00000644.3",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a2"
        },
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.27",
          "n": "e-bu-ku-nim-ma",
          "ref": "x00000644.4",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a3"
        },
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.28",
          "n": "e-bu-uk-ma",
          "ref": "x00000644.5",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a4"
        },
        {
          "type": "form",
          "cbd_id": "x00000644.29",
          "n": "i-bu-ka-ma",
          "ref": "x00000644.6",
          "icount": "3",
          "ipct": "23",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a5"
        }
      ],
      "norms": [
        {
          "id": "x00000644.30",
          "n": "ābuk",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a8"
        },
        {
          "id": "x00000644.31",
          "n": "ābuka",
          "icount": "4",
          "ipct": "31",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a0"
        },
        {
          "id": "x00000644.32",
          "n": "ēbakūma",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a2"
        },
        {
          "id": "x00000644.33",
          "n": "ēbukma",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a4"
        },
        {
          "id": "x00000644.34",
          "n": "ēbukunimma",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a3"
        },
        {
          "id": "x00000644.35",
          "n": "ībukāma",
          "icount": "3",
          "ipct": "23",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a5"
        }
      ],
      "sigs": [
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.36",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:a-bu-ka=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ābuka",
          "icount": "4",
          "ipct": "31",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a0"
        },
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.37",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:a-bu-uk=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ābuk",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a8"
        },
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.38",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:e-ba-ku-ma=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ēbakūma",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a2"
        },
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.39",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:e-bu-ku-nim-ma=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ēbukunimma",
          "icount": "2",
          "ipct": "15",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a3"
        },
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.40",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:e-bu-uk-ma=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ēbukma",
          "icount": "1",
          "ipct": "8",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a4"
        },
        {
          "type": "sig",
          "id": "x00000644.41",
          "sig": "@rinap%akk:i-bu-ka-ma=abāku[lead away//lead away]V'V$ībukāma",
          "icount": "3",
          "ipct": "23",
          "xis": "akk.r0000a5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "periods": [
    {
      "p": "Neo-Assyrian",
      "icount": "14",
      "ipct": "100",
      "xis": "akk.r00009f.p.s000"
    }
  ]
}
```

*([Here](https://github.com/nerdbond/seed/tree/3ab08dc6ece68ad8e723c46b38146716c5550e86/link/text/cuneiform/oracc) is a hint at what some of the fields mean).*

You'll notice several things:

1. **The `cf` ("citation form") is `abāku`.** I don't know what "citation form" really means, but it seems to be the "entry point" into the word from a dictionary perspective, somehow. I don't know if you are supposed to pronounce this word, or if it is just like a textual hint/key or something, it's kind of blurry what this deeply means to me so far.
2. **The `cf` has a *meaning, but no Cuneiform form*.** That is, it has a definition (what seems to be just a high-level/broad "general" meaning), but it doesn't have a native written form yet, that comes in the `forms` field next.
3. **It has many `forms`, which don't themselves have any meaning.** The forms are basically just how it could be written, I guess.
4. **It has many `senses`, which have 1 definition (and part of speech).**
5. **Each sense has many `forms`.** The available forms a sense can take come from the forms defined at the top-level of the entry. It's interesting that a sense can be written (and thus pronounced) in many different ways (that seems different than English for one).

So really, it seems to me, there *should* just be "senses" (definitions, which each have a part of speech), and each sense can be written/pronounced in several ways. That would make it fit into the traditional/typical dictionary mold, where each term has a definition and possibly many variations in pronunciation.

But then we have this extra layer in this Akkadian system, the top-level stuff. It's like as if the senses are grouped into a "general meaning", or a "general sense", but you cannot pronounce the general sense, you can only pronounce the specific sense. So this "general sense" (top-level entry) is basically an *unpronounceable/unwritable thing*! That is, it doesn't seem to really exist. It seems to be just some sort of grouping mechanism in the end, to group what seem to be related senses into a higher level entity or model. So in this simple case, we have "lead away OR deliver" is grouped under the general category "lead away", but it's unpronounceable in the general structure....

Why did they do this? It kind of breaks the whole mold I had of dictionaries lol, for pretty much every other language I've studied. In every other language, you have strings of text which each can have several pronunciations, and each string can have several (sometimes unrelated) meanings. That is, the "general category" usually is the string of text, which then breaks down into several senses/pronunciations. That is different from this Akkadian case, where the general category is NOT a string of writable cuneiform, it is something more general.

My question is, is it necessary to have this general grouping mechanism in Akkadian? Why/why not? If it is necessary, it would seem to suggest that you could find other unrelated terms, and group them under other unpronounceable entities/categories as well. For other languages, this would mean we have a "term category" basically, which is the entry to the dictionary. A generic notion in a sense, a general "concept". Then from the general concept, you have a few terms/words/strings of text, which have a few meanings.

I don't know, something feels off about this, and I'm sure I'm missing something. Hoping to shed some light on what is going on here, why it is like this.

Comment: I'm very curious how you've been working with dictionaries for a lot of languages and never heard of a citation form.

Comment: I'm very curious why the downvotes. That said, I am coming at things from an outsider perspective, unfettered by the traditional dogma. So I miss things that might seem obvious to you, but it will be a good thing in the end, not to get bogged down by legacy practices. I still have a lot of work to do as well.

Comment: I can't recall ever having seen a dictionary use the term "citation form". 6 dictionaries that I just picked up didn't mention such a concept.

Comment: @user6726 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)

Comment: @Lance You have to understand the standard perspectives and practices in order to not be bogged down by them.

Comment: Perhaps even more importantly, no matter how much you may wish to avoid "traditional dogma", you can't expect to make use of a reference work (or a dictionary or a database) compiled using traditional methods without understanding the dogma it is based on. You might as well try to use a calculator without understanding what the funny symbols like "1" and "2" and "+" mean.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I said, look at an actual dictionary and find the term "citation form". Focus on the point, which is that it is not  reasonable to find it cavalier when a persons reads dictionaries and "still" hasn't encountered the expression "citation form". It's fine to chastise a person for not having sufficiently studied linguistic theory, but it is wrong to snarkily criticize a person for failing to see the invisible, namely "the meaning of 'citation form' as attested in the dictionaries that you have been reading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to keep track of some data about each word in English. You go through a corpus and record every time someone uses each word; let's use "walk" as an example. You also record every time they use "walked", "walks", "walking", and so on; for each of these instances, you write down the title and author and date of use.

It would be useful to store the data about all these different forms of the word together. After all, if someone's wondering how early the word "walk" was used, they probably mean how early *any form* of the word was recorded, not just "walk" in particular.

So you've bundled together the data about all these different forms. What do you label the bundle as? You could call it just "word #743", but that's not very helpful for indexing. Instead, you'd probably choose *one* form of the word to use as the index, perhaps "walk", and label the bundle that. This is the *citation form*: the form you use to look up information about the word.

Can you pronounce the citation form? Sure. "Walk" is a perfectly fine word. It just also happens to be the form that was chosen to stand for all the others, for indexing purposes. But it doesn't have a title and author and date attached to it, because it's not a particular *instance of usage*. It's a way of talking about the word in general. (In this analogy, title and author and date correspond to the cuneiform transcription.)

Now let's suppose you want to record some extra information about each instance of usage: whether they mean "walk" as in "walk around", or "walk" as in "walk the dog". Not especially difficult, technologically speaking. You make a table of instances, and a table of senses, and have pointers back and forth somewhere. Nice and simple.

But, putting pointers into JSON is difficult. And that's why the data is arranged so weirdly here. Each form (instance of usage) is connected to a sense (potential meaning), and this is apparently how they chose to represent that in JSON. On the backend, presumably it's all stored in some kind of relational database that handles things more clearly.

Can you pronounce a sense? Sure, but they're all pronounced the same. "Walk" (around) and "walk" (a dog) are the same word, just two different ways to use that word. That's why they're part of the same entry. *Abāku* is a single verb, but it can be used in a few different ways, which is why it gets multiple senses but a single entry in the lexicon.

Comment: Ok interesting, I am starting to see a little and get it better, still need to let that sink in. "Walk" and "walked" I would imagine as derived words, one is built from another. Maybe even "anger" vs. "angry", would they go under one vs. the other? Building one from another makes sense, it's just that the citation form seems to be more like "apple and orange" in one category, "fruit". I don't see the difference quiet yet. Why not just have one category, "thing", and call it a day, then have derived words, but nothing else.

Comment: @Lance If a language had a single word meaning both "apple" and "orange", I would expect it to have only one dictionary entry, wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, but some of the examples in the Akkadian dictionary are kind of like that IMO. I'd have to inspect a lot more of them to really know for sure though.