# Which part of the Oracc data is to be used for pronunciation of Akkadian words?

Tags: syntax, phonology, akkadian

I shared [this Oracc RINAP JSON example](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5f6292088acbc5d9ce3430231aa450ce) in my [last post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47424/why-are-there-top-level-words-in-akkadian-dictionary-all-of-which-are-unpronoun), but now I'm focusing on how to automatically generate an IPA version of each Akkadian "word", from some sort of input word/text.

It appears there are two types of texts, two syntaxes:

- **The "Cuneiform"-transformable syntax** (glyph-syntax let's call it). This is used to be able to [cuneify](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/doc/help/visitingoracc/reusingoracc/index.html#h_cuneify) texts. So from the `forms.n` we have like `a-bu-ka`, and that would be like [this](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/cgi-bin/cuneify?input=a-bu-ka&button=Cuneify&project=doc2%2Fvisitor):   .
- **The pronunciation-syntax**. This has [letters](https://enenuru.proboards.com/thread/376/sounds-akkadian-language-phonology?page=1) like `â` and `š` and apparently there is a 1<>1 mapping between those letters and IPA sounds, as far as my understanding goes.

But do I have all this correct so far? I'm not sure. Can you not use the "glyph-syntax" for pronunciation?

- Am I to use the glyph-syntax only for converting to Cuneiform (are there any docs on this too)?
- Am I to assume the [cf](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5f6292088acbc5d9ce3430231aa450ce#file-abaku-json-L8) field form like `abāku` or `abūbāniš` or `baʾāšu` are for pronunciation? Or is the glyph-syntax somehow also for pronunciation, or is it somewhere else I haven't found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cuneiform writing system doesn't represent the sounds of Akkadian especially well. For example, Akkadian had three vowel lengths, but there were only two ways of writing these in cuneiform: plene vs non-plene spellings. Short vowels are rarely written plene, long vowels are sometimes written plene, and overlong vowels are usually written plene. Similarly, the language had separate `/i/` and `/e/` vowels, but the same cuneiform sign was used for both *zi* and *ze* (and also for *ṣí* and *ṣé* and…).

So what you call the "glyph-syntax" is a representation of the cuneiform spelling, and what you call the "pronunciation-syntax" is properly called a *normalized form*—a representation of how we think the word actually existed in the mind of an Akkadian-speaker, unbound by the limitations of the writing system. The cuneiform transcription is what you should look at for the writing; the normalized form is what you should look at for the pronunciation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that clears things up. Can you elaborate more on what would go wrong when trying to use the normalized form for pronunciation?

Comment: @Lance The normalized form is what you should use for the pronunciation.

Comment: It must not be the [`cf`](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5f6292088acbc5d9ce3430231aa450ce#file-abaku-json-L8) then (still need to understand what that is exactly), so I must need to look somewhere else in that JSON there? Maybe that's what the `norms` section is, hmm, I'm [not sure](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/doc/help/lemmatising/signatures/index.html). AH, you called it the `normalized` from, so it must be that!?

Comment: @Lance Yes, `norms` is normalized forms.

Comment: Ok great, now I need to understand [why/how they are treating Sumerian different](https://www.reddit.com/r/asklinguistics/comments/168isns/how_to_determine_the_pronunciation_from_sumerian/), and are asking _not_ to use the `norms` field, but instead use the `morphs` field. Almost... there.... Thanks.

Comment: @Lance Sumerian phonology is much less understood than Akkadian.